# Эпилог или Конец?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Эпилог - Послесловие (от греч.)(т.е. после слов, или я не совсем правильно понимаю?), заключительная часть произведения. А конец это до эпилога или после? Правильно ли сказать "Каков эпилог в этом произведении", если хочешь узнать конец? Какое конкретно различие между этими терминами? Или может быть различия нет совершенно? Заранее Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Эпилог - заключительная часть, прибавленная к законченному художественному произведению и не обязательно связанная с ним неразрывным развитием действия.

Если Вы хотите сказать о последних страницах романа,следует сказать "конец романа", если о том, чем закончилось действие,- "развязка":"Какова развязка? Чем закончилось действие?" Эпилог рассказывает о том, что случилось с героями после развязки, поэтому он и называется послесловием.

Т.е. в конце романа может быть эпилог, а может его и не быть.Книга может закончиться развязкой.

Answer (score 1):

Конец  книги и ее эпилог относятся к разным описательным категориям. КОНЕЦ – это общее понятие, отнесенное к различным предметам, существующим во времени и в пространстве:  К. дороги. К. улицы.   К.  зимы.  К.  книги. ЭПИЛОГ – это литературный термин, связанный с развитием сюжетной линии.

КОНЕЧНЫЙ (итоговый) момент в развитии действия характеризуется несколькими терминами (эпилог, послесловие, развязка).

ЭПИЛОГ (греч. έπίλογος — послесловие ← ἐπι — на, сверх + λόγος — слово), а также ПРОЛОГ, не включаются в развитие сюжетной линии.  Это описание событий до начала действия (пролог) и после его окончания (эпилог). Эпилог и пролог не являются обязательными элементами, но, к примеру, они часто встречаются в романах Достоевского и Тургенева.Есть еще ПОСЛЕСЛОВИЕ,  но эпилог —  это рассказ, а  послесловие обычно является размышлением.

РАЗВЯЗКА — это итог развития художественного конфликта и конец повествования. По определению Аристотеля, развязка начинается с момента свершения «переворота в судьбе героя» и заканчивается победой или поражением последнего.

Comment: Начало  романа  не  обозначают  этим  словом,  а  в  конце  романа  слово  конец  иногда  встречается  ( или  можно  представить,  что  написано  "Конец" ).  Если  у  романа  будет  эпилог,  где  его  поместят:  до  этого  слова  или  после ?